# Library project recompilation and recompilation of dependent projects

Tags: android, dependencies, android-library, library-project

If we build project A as library project and project B as a standard project which includes the library project A, what happens when I change code in library project A (i.e. project A gets recompiled)?

Next time I recompile project B, does it automatically include the new code in project A? Does it look at the version within Manifest in project A to understand if the library project has been changed or does it simply look at the timestamp of the jar file of project A to see if it has been recompiled since it was last included in project B?

Answer (score 1):

I think eclipse automatically compiles .class files of project A and B recognizes this changes but when you are going to distribute your app you need to clean your workspace and build it again in order to see the new changes of project A in project B. This is cause of eclipse compiles class and later makes the conversion to dalvik class files.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there are two kinds of dependencies.

1) is setup under "Project Properties"/"Java Build Path". You let one Eclipse project depend on another project so changes to say project A will rebuild project B.

2) is setup under "Project Properties"/"Android". You tell the android tools that Project B depends on an android library (Project A) at runtime. I don't think that Project B will be rebuilt if Project A changes if only this dependency method is used.